# Why is rand::Rng able to work in a no-std environment even when I have not set default-features = false?

Tags: rust, bare-metal

Shouldn't I need to [disable rand's `std` feature flag](https://rust-random.github.io/book/features.html?highlight=no_Std#core-only-no_std) before being able to use it in a `no_std` environment?

**lib.rs**

```rust
#![no_std]

use rand::Rng;

pub fn random_small() -> u8{
    rand::thread_rng().gen::<u8>()
}
```

**Cargo.toml**

```
[dependencies]

rand = "0.6.5"
```

I am not using `#![no_std]` in my **main.rs** though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need to disable rand's `std` feature in order to use it in an environment where `std` is unavailable. However, if `std` *is* available, not disabling the `std` feature will still work.

The `#![no_std]` changes your crate's prelude from the `std` prelude to the `core` prelude. The `std` prelude looks like:

```
extern crate std;
use std::prelude::v1::*;
```

The `core` prelude is the same but with `core` instead of `std`. This means that, unless you write `extern crate std;`, your crate doesn't depend on `std` directly.

However, `#![no_std]` has no effect on your dependencies. [The Rust Reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/crates-and-source-files.html#preludes-and-no_std) has a relevant warning:

> ⚠️ Warning: Using `no_std` does not prevent the standard library from being linked in. It is still valid to put `extern crate std;` into the crate and dependencies can also link it in.

Therefore, if `std` is available for your target and one of your dependencies needs `std`, then it will be able to use it. On the other hand, if `std` isn't available for the target, then crates that try to use it (either implicitly or explicitly) will fail to compile.

Comment: So `Rand` still uses `std` then ? Wouldn't it be a problem if I strictly need `no_std` ?